# Put text near to attribute when you change the size of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with text and `<div>`, currently the text should be under the `<div>` and I set 
`margin-top:300px`, which looks fine.

I need that when user minimize the screen the text will be under the `<div>` **without any space**,how should I do that?

This is the code for the text

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 300px">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="rightText">My text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So whats your actual problem I dont even close to get your prob will you make a fiddle.

Comment: the text is far from the div  becouse 300px

Comment: Share a fiddle link of your working code with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10%">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try media query for instance

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
    .class{
       margin-top:0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure how should I  use it inside the text ,can you provide example?